# Is there way to define two generic types in method declaration

Tags: java, lambda

In some case, type of input argument and type of return value is diff

for instance: i can use following code:

```
public interface Proc2 {
    <T> T call(Object o);
}
```

but i wanna use following:

```
public interface Proc2 {
    <T><T2> T call(T2 o);
}
```

**my question is:** how to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use comma

```
public interface Proc2 {
    <T, T2> T call(T2 o);
}
```